# How to calculate distance from camera to object using CV toolbox?

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

I created a custom object detector which works pretty well but i am getting **NaN** for all values in my matrix. I found this out after debugging the code and the bounded region in my image shows **NaN meters**.
I used the code from Matlab to compute the distance but I do not know if that is a general method of calulcating the distance. Below is the code.

```
points3D = reconstructScene(disparityMapBM,stereoParams);
points3D = points3D ./ 1000;
trainingData = objectDetectorTrainingData(gTruth);
myAFCdetector = trainACFObjectDetector(trainingData,'NumStages',5, 'NegativeSamplesFactor',2);

img = imread('Right_Image.jpg');

[bboxes,scores] = detect(myAFCdetector,img);

for i = 1:length(scores)
   annotation = sprintf('Confidence = %.1f',scores(i));
   I1 = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bboxes(i,:),annotation);
end

figure
imshow(I1)

centroids = [round(bboxes(:, 1) + bboxes(:, 3) / 2), ...
    round(bboxes(:, 2) + bboxes(:, 4) / 2)];

% Find the 3-D world coordinates of the centroids.
centroidsIdx = sub2ind(size(disparityMapBM), centroids(:, 2), centroids(:, 1));
X = points3D(:, :, 1);
Y = points3D(:, :, 2);
Z = points3D(:, :, 3);
centroids3D = [X(centroidsIdx)'; Y(centroidsIdx)'; Z(centroidsIdx)'];

% Find the distances from the camera in meters.
dists = sqrt(sum(centroids3D .^ 2));

% Display the detected people and their distances.
labels = cell(1, numel(dists));
for i = 1:numel(dists)
    labels{i} = sprintf('%0.2f meters', dists(i));
end
figure;
imshow(insertObjectAnnotation(I1, 'rectangle', bboxes, labels));
title('Detected People');
```

I found out NaN matrix at **centroids3D**. Could there be any reason why I am getting these matrix filled with NaN?

```
Centoids3D = [Nan NaN NaN NaN; Nan NaN NaN NaN; Nan NaN NaN NaN]
```

Comment: Did check how your 3D points (the values inside points3D)  look like ? It is possible that they contains invalid points. They are calculated from a disparity map, which can be noisy (and even contain some zeros, which would mean infinite distance). If all your 3D points are correct (no NaN), then you should check the indices (centroidsIdx) that you use to select the 3D points from each 2D centroid.

Comment: The centroids contains a 4x2 double matrix while the centroidsIdx contains 4x1 double matix but the values are pretty large which are 298760, 434672, 482956, 474044. I am still not able to wrap my head around this. May I will do some filtering after the disparity map. Perhaps it could change the results

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take reference object for which distance is known to get focal length and then its feasible to find the distance of object from camera.

[Here is the full tutorial for reference.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/)